# simple_form self for check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form

I have simple_form input :check_boxes for a field which is serialized Array.

```
f.input :material_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: @materials.collect {|m| [m.name, m.id]}
```

I need to select a checkbox if material id is in the collection. So I need something like

```
input_html: {checked: @foo.material_ids.includes?(self???)}
```

If there is something like "self" in that case ?

Comment: In ruby "self" used within **internal** methods of objects:  it's not used as a variable name for 'the object currently in scope', in the way that `this` functions in javascript for example.  In your view code you would normally loop through @materials and store each instance as a variable inside the loop, eg `@materials.each do |material|`.  You would then be referring to 'material', not self.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `f.object`. That gives you the object that the form builder `f` is currently wrapping.